# redmine reinstall

Tags: redmine, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Redmine on Ubuntu 12.0.4.

I moved along nicely following the below instructions on the Redmine site:

---

Installing the latest Redmine

The package with Ubuntu 10.04 is stuck in the 0.9.x branch and Ubuntu 12.04 is stuck in the 1.3.x branch. A PPA exists that has the latest branch here: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/redmine

To install redmine using the PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/redmine
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
```

---

Then I hit an error towards the end of the execution of the last command above. I Googled to find a fix for the error but could not find any. So, I located all redmine folders installed until then, removed mysql empty db 'redmine' and the associated user. Now, I am trying to reinstall Redmine using the last command above, but keep getting the following error.

```
root@hrrankdev1:~# apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
redmine is already the newest version.
redmine-mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up redmine (2.1.2+dfsg1-1~precise+13) ...
chown: cannot access `/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing redmine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redmine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think I am way beyond fixing the original error. All I am looking for is to remove all traces of previous aborted installation and install it afresh. Any suggestions on how to proceed to successfully install is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Bitnami Redmine Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine).

I had a go at installing Redmine from source like Etienne has suggested. While I did manage to get it going on Ubuntu 12.04 it was a bit of a pain.

I'm now using the Bitnami Redmine VM. Setup is a breeze, just follow the instructions [here](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Virtual_Appliances_Quick_Start_Guide)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to install Redmine using Ubuntu/Debian repositories.  They always lag behind current version of Redmine.

You better to install Redmine using latest source code from main development tree.  Just follow the instructions here :

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

This a more manual approach than using Ubuntu packages but you will get the latest and greatest features.  Instructions are clear, just follow them in order.